# SQL Server: Joining three tables while showing null matches

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have spent a couple of hours trying to figure out this particular join. I have these three SQL Server tables (assume all the requisite indexes and foreign keys):

```
create table [mykey] (keyname varchar(32) not null);
go
create table [myinstance] (
instancename varchar(48) not null);
go
create table [mypermissions] (
keyname varchar(32),
instancename varchar(48),
permission int not null);
go
insert into [mykey] (keyname) values ('test_key_1'), ('test_key_2'), ('test_key_3');
GO
insert into [myinstance] (instancename) values ('sqlexpress'), ('std2008'), ('ent2012');
GO
insert into mypermissions (keyname, instancename, permission) values
    ('test_key_1', 'sqlexpress', 1),
    ('test_key_1', 'std2008', 0),
    ('test_key_2', 'ent2012', 1),
    ('test_key_2', 'sqlexpress', 0)
GO
```

I am trying to create a join that shows all the permissions for keynames while also showing where specific permissions are missing.  I would like the output to look like this (order unimportant):

```
keyname     instancename   permission
----------  ------------   ----------
test_key_1  sqlexpress     1
test_key_1  std2008        0
test_key_1  ent2012        NULL
test_key_2  ent2012        1
test_key_2  sqlexpress     0
test_key_2  std2008        NULL
test_key_3  sqlexpress     NULL
test_key_3  std2008        NULL
test_key_3  ent2012        NULL
```

but instead it looks like this:

```
keyname     instancename   permission
----------  ------------   ----------
test_key_1  sqlexpress     1
test_key_1  std2008        0
test_key_2  ent2012        1
test_key_2  sqlexpress     0
test_key_3  NULL           NULL
```

I have spent a couple of hours with all sorts of joins with no luck. Maybe what I want to do is impossible.  Here is the most recent one I tried:

```
select k.keyname, p.instancename, p.permission from mykey k
    full join mypermissions p on (k.keyname = p.keyname)
    full join myinstance i on p.instancename = i.instancename
```

Is what I am trying to do possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use [`CROSS JOIN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join) to get all combinations of keyname and instancename before you join the third table.  Look at this query

```
SELECT *
FROM myinstance mi
CROSS JOIN mykey mk
```

This will output

```
instancename    keyname
------------    ----------
sqlexpress      test_key_1
std2008         test_key_1
ent2012         test_key_1
sqlexpress      test_key_2
std2008         test_key_2
ent2012         test_key_2
sqlexpress      test_key_3
std2008         test_key_3
ent2012         test_key_3
```

You can use [`LEFT JOIN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Outer_join) to the third table and extract the columns required as shown in the below query:

```
SELECT mk.keyname, mi.instancename, mp.permission
FROM myinstance mi
CROSS JOIN mykey mk
LEFT JOIN mypermissions mp ON mk.keyname = mp.keyname AND mi.instancename = mp.instancename
ORDER BY mk.keyname, mi.instancename
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
select a.keyname, a.instancename, p.permission 
from (select k.keyname, i.instancename from mykey k cross join myinstance i) a
left join mypermissions p on p.keyname = a.keyname and p.instancename = a.instancename
```

Comment: what is the internal join based on here?

Comment: it is a cross join, all rows from the first table multiplied by all rows from the second table. run just that to see what it produces.

Comment: When I run this query, I get this error `Incorrect syntax near ')'.`  Did you miss `CROSS` keyword? :)

Comment: you also need to fix typo in `isntancename` ;)